# JMeter encode URL

Tags: automation, jmeter, httprequest, performance-testing, encode

I have to test the below URL that contains special char:

url\search.html?q=*&Filters=template_fac_s:3f87222389034212a868c5c0cd12cacc|market_l1_fac_sm:e73956c2506442399dd73ed1eb0ec165

I am getting this error:

Response message: Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in query at index 121: url/search.html?q=*&Filters=template_fac_s:3f87222389034212a868c5c0cd12cacc|market_l1_fac_sm:e73956c2506442399dd73ed1eb0ec165

I think I need to encode the URL but I do not know how to do it . Does anyone know how to do this , can someone help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides [__urlencode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) function which replaces characters which are not allowed in URL with url-encoded equivalents

References:

- [Understanding HTML Form Encoding: URL Encoded and Multipart Forms](https://dev.to/sidthesloth92/understanding-html-form-encoding-url-encoded-and-multipart-forms-3lpa)
- [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)